# Jenkins job retrieving values from Git

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins job pipeline, that has a "build job" option, which references and executes a second jenkins job. That second Jenkins job references to a third Jenkinsfile stored in Github.

The third Jenkinsile has several stages. Issue is, that first Jenkinsfile should execute just one stage from that Jenkinsfile.

I think it's best to create a parameter in that one stage in Github Jenkinsfile and have the 1st Jenkins job retrieve the value of that parameter.

How to achieve that, what sort of parameter would that be that can access Github Jenkinsfile?

Tried adding different jobs to execute different stages based on job name, but got stuck, because Github Jenkinsfile cannot retrieve Jenkins job name.

Answer (score 1):

> Issue is, that first Jenkinsfile should execute just one stage from that Jenkinsfile.

If I understand your setup correctly, it is not possible. A `build` step runs a job, and a job runs the whole Jenkinsfile.

> I think it's best to create a parameter in that one stage in Github Jenkinsfile and have the 1st Jenkins job retrieve the value of that parameter.

Jenkinsfile stages don't have their own parameters, they only can use the pipeline parameters defined beforehand.

But, at the same time, this leads to a possible solution.

You can use a [`when`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) condition in any stage of the pipeline.

For example, if you need only the first stage to be executed when the build is triggered by any other job, you can do something like this:

```java
// Jenkinsfile #3

pipeline {
  // ...
  stages {
    stage('First') {
      when { triggeredBy 'BuildUpstreamCause' }
      steps {
        // ...
      }
    }
    stage('Second') {
      when { not triggeredBy 'BuildUpstreamCause' }
      steps {
        // ...
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can pass some parameter value from your `build` step of the first Jenkinsfile, like this:

```java
// Jenkinsfile #1
// ...
  steps {
    // ...
    build job: 'some/job/path',
          parameters: [
            booleanParam name: 'runFirstStageOnly',
              value: true
          ]
  }
// ...
```

And check for this parameter value in `when` blocks:

```java
// Jenkinsfile #3

pipeline {
  // ...
  stages {
    stage('First') {
      when { 
        expression {
          params.runFirstStageOnly
        }
      }
      steps {
        // ...
      }
    }
    stage('Second') {
      when { 
        not expression { 
          params.runFirstStageOnly
        }
      }
      steps {
        // ...
      }
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

You can combine the conditions to match your exact requirements - there are many built-in ones, and with `expression` and `allOf`/`anyOf` you can do everything.